# Ajax And Local Network gives "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header"

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, get

I need to send a GET request to a file on the local network. But I always get a No Acces-Control-Allow-Origin header. I am doing this from my pc already in the local network. But it is the same when I do this over my domainname. I am doing this in javascript with an Ajax-call to a php script.

this is my ajax-call:

```
$.ajax({
    data: {},
    url: 'http://192.168.2.100/php/checkForHomeNetwork.php',
    method: 'GET',
    datatype: 'json',
    async: false,
    cache: false,
    timeout: 30000,
    success: function(msg) {
        alert(msg);
    }
});
```

Comment: don't use async false ... it is deprecated by browsers and you should be seeing warning about it in console. It is a terrible practice since it blocks the UI

Comment: Yes, my UI needs to wait before doing something else, how can I fix this?

Comment: Consume the data in success callback or  promise returned from `$.ajax` ... see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call

Comment: Oke, and that wil do exactly the same as assync? will it run the code folowing on the ajax call or will it alwayswait till the ajaxcall is succes or failed

Comment: success callback fires when data has been received

Comment: that needs to be all my other code then?

Comment: whatever is dependent on that ajax. Can wrap the other code in a function and call that function if it helps organization better

Comment: everything depends on that ajax

Comment: ok...wrap everything in a function then

Comment: Do you know if there is a way to create a cross-domain request in ajax

Comment: I see now what You mean with blocking the UI. before I had no problem but now after adding a new must-have feature for my website the webiste blocks completely till all ajaxcalls are completed. Thanks

Comment: I am trying to rewrite this, but I am using a for loop, and each iteration, there needs I make a async ajaxcall, Is there a way to do this?

Comment: yes ..numerous ways. Suggest start new question. There are also lots and lots of posts on this site about it

Comment: For detailed tutorial explanation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The same-origin policy doesn't care about what network you're on. If the domain portion of the URL (including "http"/"https", the domain name string, and port number) are not exactly the same, then it's considered to be a cross-domain request.

The PHP script can of course be made to include the appropriate headers when it sees a request from that trusted domain.

Comment: Yes i have read that somewhere but can't how I need to add the other domains and portnumers

Comment: @KoenVanLooveren it's something you have to do from the PHP service you're invoking. [Here is some information.](https://remysharp.com/2011/04/21/getting-cors-working) You can probably find many other examples out there.

Comment: But then it is serverside? I need to check if the client can reach that php file. Not the server

Comment: But that is serverside? Isn't it?

Comment: You can't do it from the client. The browser will simply disallow access to different domains *unless* the target URL responds with correct headers. It's a security measure and the browser deliberately stops you from solving the problem in the client (JavaScript) code.